# Как получить путь до скрипта tcl без его имени?

Tags: tcl

Пользуюсь Xilinx Vivado 2020. 
Как получить путь до tcl скрипта без имени самого скрипта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте это для Tcl версии 8.3 (в Vivado 2020):

```
set ScriptDir [file normalize [file dirname [info script]]]
puts ${ScriptDir}
```

Значение:
`info script` - даёт полный путь до скрипта с его именем;
`file dirname` - даёт относительный путь к скрипту без имени;
`file normalize` - преобразовывает относительный путь в абсолютный.